# Java Springboot: Issue with CORS and error and Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

**Just a note: I have looked over 2 pages of Stack Overflow posts by others having the same problem, and I tried the many different ways on how to handle CORS but I'm still struggling with the issue. :/**

Hi all, I've been having trouble tackling this for awhile but I've been experiencing a CORS issue when I deployed my React project on Render. I also deployed the other part of the backend project(Java Springboot) as web service on Render. So the front-end is attempting to make http requests to the backend but it says:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://movie-gold-v2.onrender.com/api/v1/movies' from origin 'https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have attempted //@CrossOrigin(origins = {"https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com"}) on my RestController
I also attempted @CrossOrigins("*");
Attempted @CrossOrigins("https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com");

and even created a WebConfig.java file after that didn't work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD","GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

Then attempted other Configuration files such as:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("development")
public class DevConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS").allowedOrigins("https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com");
    }
}
```

Even attempted a CorsConfig file:

```
    @Component
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedOriginPatterns(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And here is my MovieController file for reference:

```
    @RestController
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com", allowedHeaders = "*")
//@CrossOrigin(origins = {"https://movie-gold-v1.onrender.com"})
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")

public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService service;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
        List<Movie> movies = service.findAllMovies();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movies, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{imdbId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> getSingleMovie(@PathVariable String imdbId) {
        Optional<Movie> movie = service.findMovieByImdbId(imdbId);
        if (movie.isPresent()) {
            Movie fetchedMovie = movie.get();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(fetchedMovie, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }


}
```

**Front End**,
AxiosConfig.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    // baseURL:'http://localhost:8080',
    baseURL: 'https://movie-gold-v2.onrender.com',
});
```

App.js:

```
function App() {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState();
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);

  const getMovies = async () =>{
    
    try
    {
      // const response = await api.get("/api/v1/movies");
      const response = await api.get("https://movie-gold-v2.onrender.com/api/v1/movies");

      setMovies(response.data);

    } 
    catch(err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  const getMovieData = async (movieId) => {
     
    try 
    {
        //  const response = await api.get(`/api/v1/movies/${movieId}`);
         const response = await api.get(`https://movie-gold-v2.onrender.com/api/v1/movies/${movieId}`);

        const singleMovie = response.data;

        setMovie(singleMovie);

        setReviews(singleMovie.reviews);
        

    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
      console.error(error);
    }

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home movies={movies} />} ></Route>
            <Route path="/Trailer/:ytTrailerId" element={<Trailer/>}></Route>
            <Route path="/Reviews/:movieId" element ={<Reviews getMovieData = {getMovieData} movie={movie} reviews ={reviews} setReviews = {setReviews} />}></Route>
            <Route path="*" element = {<NotFound/>}></Route>
          </Route>
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my pom.xml file in case:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>unicorndev</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>A simple API related to movies</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It seems I've attempted almost everything under the sun. I've been at this for almost a week and it's making me pull my hair out. I don't know if I will get downvoted for this from asking a question that's so common, but I just don't know what I might have missed, even after reading over the documentation and other posts. If anyone can check it out, thank you so much!

Comment: Edit your question and show the client code.

Comment: @jub0bs Hi there, I added in my Axios and App.js code, thanks